# Swift 2.3: Is there a way to figure out the state of Location Services, Location Updates?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

`locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` turns your location  updates on and `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` turns your updates off.

But I'd like to know if there's a way to get the current state. 
I tried `respondsToSelector` but that isn't quite right and probably obviously always returning `true`.

I'm trying to make a switch that'll allow the user to turn on and off location updates. 
Getting the default value of the switch is my issue.

Update for clarity: I'm trying to see the state of location updates rather than the state of the service.

Comment: It's in the docs -- CLLocationManagerDelegate

Comment: The docs handle the delegate sure, but that requires me to create my own bool to check the current state... which might be the end solution. I just find it odd that there's no easy way to check if location updates are happening or not without a manual check using the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can call  [locationServicesEnabled()](http://locationServicesEnabled()) , it returns bool value and make your switch.

I'm sorry I misunderstood your question, you can check   `authorizationStatus()` which is an enum

- if it's  `.Restricted` or `.Denied` then you don't have the permisssion
- `.AuthorizedAlways` and `.AuthorizedWhenInUse` used for significant and foreground location changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason why that doesn't fit my use case is that it's checking if Location Services are enabled on the device. So when the user says yes to allow the app to use location services that function will always return true.

Comment: isn't that what you wanted, if it returns YES , simply call `stopUpdatingLocation()`

Comment: It's a switch that's supposed to contain whether you're updating location or not. Hence you've `stopUpdatingLocation()` so it returns false. So the switch's default value is off. I suppose the better way to put it is that I'm looking for the state of location updates and not the state of the services itself.